# Loop if condition and search. What to do something if value isn't found

Tags: excel, loops, find, vba

I am trying to loop through a range and search another range if value meets `if` statement criteria. I want a msgbox to appear if search fails. I'm stuck on how to set the criteria for the search failings though.

```
Dim r2 As Range
    For Each r2 In WorkRng2
        If r2.Offset(0, 1).Value <> 0 Then
            WorkRng1.Find what:=r2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues
```

`WorkRng2` is a public range variable.

How do I finish this code to warn user search failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find` find s a range - or not. Therefore ...

```
Dim Fnd As Range
Set Fnd = WorkRng1.Find(what:=r2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Fnd Is Nothing Then
    ' Nothing found
Else
    ' Fnd holds the cell that was found
End If
```